# Data not showing up in the layout

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to get data from an API, but it seems that the data is not showing in my layout. There's no error, and the logcat seems to point toward line 58 and line 54 but I don't know what's wrong with these lines.

Here is the code:

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class WaktuAzan extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String URL_ANNOUNCEMENT = "http://interxsgroup.com.my:8887/waktu_solat/api.php?zon=SGR01";
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewAzan;
    private List<WaktuAzanList> waktuAzanLists;
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    private WaktuAzanAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.azan_layout);

        waktuAzanLists = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerViewAzan = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewAzan);
        recyclerViewAzan.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewAzan.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        getAzan();
    }

    private void getAzan() {


line 54   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ANNOUNCEMENT, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
line 58                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        waktuAzanLists.add(new WaktuAzanList(

//                                data.getString("waktu_imsak"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_subuh"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_syuruk"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_zohor"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_asar"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_maghrib"),
//                                data.getString("waktu_isyak"),
                                data.getString("nama_zon"),
                                data.getString("tarikh_masa")


                        ));

                        adapter = new WaktuAzanAdapter(waktuAzanLists,WaktuAzan.this);
                        recyclerViewAzan.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat, the log cat seems to point toward line 58 & 54.

```
2019-11-29 02:28:23.550 9673-9701/com.example.mobileapp1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9af87320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9afcab60)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.573 9673-9701/com.example.mobileapp1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9af87320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9afcab60)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"waktu_imsak":"05:41 a.m.","waktu_subuh":"05:51 a.m.","waktu_syuruk":"07:01 a.m.","waktu_zohor":"01:04 p.m.","waktu_asar":"04:26 p.m.","waktu_maghrib":"07:02 p.m.","waktu_isyak":"08:15 p.m.","kod_zon":"SGR01","nama_zon":"Gombak,Petaling,Sepang,Hulu Langat,Hulu Selangor,Rawang,S.Alam","tarikh_masa":"29-11-2019 02:28:26"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.example.mobileapp1.WaktuAzan$1.onResponse(WaktuAzan.java:58)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.example.mobileapp1.WaktuAzan$1.onResponse(WaktuAzan.java:54)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.594 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.595 9673-9673/com.example.mobileapp1 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.611 9673-9701/com.example.mobileapp1 D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9af87320: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9afcab60)
2019-11-29 02:28:23.618 9673-9701/com.example.mobileapp1 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x877c9b80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x877f22b0
```

Comment: That `response` would be a `JSONObject`, not a `JSONArray`. If you go to http://interxsgroup.com.my:8887/waktu_solat/api.php in your browser, it gives a simple description of what you should be expecting.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how I should write it instead? Been trying to parse it as jsonobject as you said, but I seems to still not able to do it even after looking up example online.

Comment: Well, you basically had most everything right, for what that URL was returning. It's just that your code was expecting an array, instead of a single object. All you really needed to do was `JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);`, and get rid of the loop. I don't really know what you're trying to do, though, because it seems kinda pointless to put that single object in a `RecyclerView`. Also, that URL is now giving an error, so I don't know what's happening there.

Comment: I did it! thanks a lot man :D. I am still a beginner so I am just doing whatever I knew work. So since I work a lot with recyclerview, its the only way I know how to do things.